# Check multiple buttons with same id with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I'm trying to build a website where people can make a reservation, I'm using a database to collect the times and php to display it. It displays all times within 5 days, including the ones that aren't available. They are displayed as buttons, all sharing the same id. I got stuck at the last step, disabling the buttons with unavailable times.

Since the only difference between these buttons is their background color (grey for unavailable and green for available) I figured I'd use a javascript function in which it checks the background colors of the boxes in a condition and then the grey ones get disabled and the green ones give a form. However: it'll only check the color of the first button and all buttons give the same result as that one.

My page will always display 50 buttons, so I thought I could just use a while loop with an auto-decrement at the end, however I can't seem to find out how to check the next button, it will now only check the same button again and again. Here's a part of the php-code to show the buttons with the right color (I've take some irrelevant parts out):

```
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
    $color = "##8fd6a5";
    if (!empty($row['unavailable'])){
        $color = "##9b9393";
    }

    $time= new DateTime($row['time']);

    if ($time->format('H') == '08'){
        echo '<button id="myBtn" onload="disablebuttons()" class="buttonstyle" 
               style="background-color: '.$color.'">'.$time>format('m/d H:i').'</button>';
    }
}
```

This works entirely, but since all buttons have id="myBtn" when disablebuttons() executes, it only looks at the first button, following this code:

```
function disablebuttons() {
    var amountButton = 50;
    while (amountButton > 0){
        var buttondisable = document.getElementById("myBtn");

        if (buttondisable.style.backgroundColor == "rgb(155, 147, 147)"){
            document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;    
            amountButton--;
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to delete the variable at the end of the while loop and place the "var buttondisable = document.getElementById("myBtn");" inside the loop, however this did not work.

Comment: You cannot have same IDs. IDs are unique in HTML.

Comment: That would go against the natural behaviour of IDs. Define classed rather than IDs.

Comment: don't use same id

Comment: increment id and just loop in the script ! easiest way i guess

Answer (score 0):

IDs need to be unique so you need to use different ids for each button. To group them, give then same **class** say `available` if they are available `unavailable` if its not available. Something like this:

```
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc())
{
    $color = "##8fd6a5";
    $class= 'available'
    if (!empty($row['unavailable']))
    {
        $color = "##9b9393";
        $class= 'unavailable'
    }
    $time= new DateTime($row['time']);
    if ($time->format('H') == '08')
    {
        echo '<button id="myBtn" onload="disablebuttons()" class="buttonstyle '.$class.'" style="background-color: '.$color.'">'.$time>format('m/d H:i').'</button>';
    }
}
```

Now on javascript you can target specific buttons only like this:

```
var buttondAvailable = document.getElementByClassName("available");
```

OR

```
var buttondUnavailable = document.getElementByClassName("unavailable");
```

Comment: `document.getElementByClass` - Is this a new ES6 function? (/s) Or did you mean [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)?

Comment: I changed `document.getElementByClass` to `document.getElementByClassName`. You could have just edited my answer too instead of downvoting

Comment: Sure, I could've easily edited but then it is *your* answer right? You'd never have spotted your mistake then would you. Please don't wrongly assume that I down-voted your answer. I appreciate the fact that humans make mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

The `id` attribute should be unique in the same document, so use common classes instead of `id`'s for your buttons like :

```
if ($time->format('H') == '08'){
    echo '<button onload="disablebuttons()" class="buttonstyle myBtn" 
          style="background-color: '.$color.'">'.$time>format('m/d H:i').'</button>';
}
```

Then in your JS code loop through all the buttons using **[`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)** :

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('myBtn');

for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
{
     //Your logic here

     var button = buttons[i];

     if (button.style.backgroundColor == "rgb(155, 147, 147)")
     {
         button.disabled = true;    
     }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

if you get the parent element and loop their childrens, you can check each element and his background and disable it.

```
    $('#mydiv').children('button').each(function () {
        // "this" is the current element in the loop
        if($(this).css("background-color") == "rgb(155, 147, 147)"){
           $(this).disabled = true;
        } 
    });
```

Comment: Be careful.. there's no jQuery tag in the OP.

Comment: Thats right, but appart of the selectors, is any sentence that can not be replaced with vanillaJS?

Comment: it was a rhetorical question